# Demonstrating triviality of images of Hurewicz map

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose I have some nontrivial element $\rho$ of $\pi_n(S^m)$ where $n>m$, for concreteness, view $S^n$ as $\partial \Delta^{n+1}$ where I take the evident fundamental class in $H_n(S^n )$. Obviously, $\rho$ has to lie in the kernel of the Hurewicz homomorphism since the (reduced) homology of $S^m$ is concentrated in degee $m$.

Is it possible to explicitly describe the chain in $C_{m+1}(S^m)$ that demonstrates the triviality? Is it true that the map $\rho$ is always null cobordant (which I believe is stronger than null homologous)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a map $F: \Omega_*(S^n) \to \Omega_* \oplus \Omega_{*-n}$ which gives an isomorphism. First we write down the map, then we will check why it is an isomorphism. Call the components $F = (F_1, F_2)$.

First we have $F_1 = \Omega_*(S^n) \to \Omega_*(\text{pt})$ the induced map. That is, forget that you have a map $P \to S^n$ for some probing manifold $P$, and just consider $P$ itself as an element of the bordism group.

Second we have $F_2 = \Omega_*(S^n) \to \Omega_{*-n}$ defines as follows. If $\sigma: P \to S^n$ is your bordism class, pick a regular value of $x$. Then $F_2([\sigma]) = [\sigma^{-1}(x)]$. The bordism class is independent of the regular value chosen and of the bordism class of $\sigma$ itself, both of which are easy to see.

First: this is surjective. To see that it has $([M^k], [N^{k-n}])$ in the image, just consider the map $\sigma: M \sqcup N \times S^n \to S^n$, given on one component by the constant map $\sigma(M) = x$ and on the other component by $\sigma(N, p) = p$. It is evident that in this $F_1([\sigma]) = [M]$, because the second factor is null-bordant; and because any $p \neq x$ is a regular value we find $F_2([\sigma]) = [N]$.

Second: this is injective. This is the claim that you wanted to see explicitly; there are of course algebraic proofs but why not just write down the null-bordism.

So suppose $F_2([\sigma]) = [0]$. I claim that $\sigma$ is bordant to a constant map. Then the fact that $F_1([\sigma]) = 0$ finishes the job --- we have a constant map from a null-bordant manifold, so we may null-bord the manifold and extend that map by the constant map.

Proof: Near a regular value, $\sigma$ looks like $\pi_2: N \times D^n \to D^n$, where $N = \sigma^{-1}(p)$ and $D^k$ is a small disc centered at $p$. Take the manifold $P$ and delete $N \times \text{int}(D^n)$, pasting on $W \times S^n$ in its place, where $W$ bounds $N$. Call this $P'$. There is a natural map $\sigma': P' \to S^n$ given by $\sigma$ on $P' - \text{int}(W) \times S^{n-1}$, and on $W \times S^{n-1}$ our map is $\sigma'(W, p) = p$.

I claim that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are bordant. You can obtain the bordism as $P \times I \cup_{N \times D^n \times \{1\}} W \times D^n$, the same way you normally do with surgery. It is clear how $\widetilde \sigma$ extends across this to restrict to $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ on the respective boundaries: $\widetilde \sigma$ agrees with $\sigma$ on $P \times I$, and on $W \times D^n$ it is given by $\widetilde \sigma(w, p) = p$.

Thus $\sigma$ is bordant to a null-homotopic map. Null-homotoping it, $\sigma$ is bordant to a constant map. We have constructed the explicit chain as desired.

---

Try doing this in the case of the Hopf map. You will see that (one instantiation of) the manifold we have constructed is $\Bbb{CP}^2 \setminus D^4$, with the projection to $\Bbb{CP}^1$ being a disc-bundle. This is the usual null-bordism of the Hopf map, and works just as well for the quaternionic Hopf map $S^7 \to \Bbb{HP}^1$. I do not have opinions on the octonionic Hopf map.

Comment: Hi, this is a very nice geometric construction. I am a little groggy this morning, what exactly does the injectivity in your claim correspond to from my question? Are you saying the preimage of a regular value of a map between spheres should be nullcobordant?

Comment: Ah I see, the manifold must be stably parallelizable, so its characteristic numbers vanish, so it is null cobordant.